# Is there any Possible way to send friend request to facebook user using Facebook Api in react native 2019

Tags: firebase, react-native, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

i need to implement a functionality that user1 send a friend request to user 2 within my app. both users are loggedin(facebook auth) to my app.

I am using react-native-fbsdk and firebase for login and other stuff.

How do I send friend request to other user within my app.

I tried some methods but failed

1, I can redirect the User1 to User2 profile but it needs (id) like www.facebook.com/2114214515  ,this numeric Id is no
more provided by facebook sdk.   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user  (see field third_party_id)

2,There are some Dialogs available in Facebook SDK 
Like Share Or Send  but they useful when user1 and user2 already are friends, which is not the required condition

3,The other way is to send Request Dialog , I applied it https://github.com/Ferchost/React-Native-Platzi/blob/master/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/js/FBGameRequestDialog.js

```
requestDialog (){
    var tmp = this;
    GameRequestDialog.canShow(this.state.gameRequestContent).then(
      function(canShow) {
        if (canShow) {
          return GameRequestDialog.show(tmp.state.gameRequestContent);
        }
      }
    ).then(
      function(result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          alert('Request cancelled');
        } else {
          alert('Request success with postId: ' + result.postId);
        }
      },
      function(error) {
        alert('Request fail with error: ' + error);
      }
    );
  }
```

but this is only for games not apps

So please tell me how to send friend request from my app to other user.

if this is officially not included in facebook sdk , there should a possible side way or hack to this?

Comment: There is no official way to send friend requests, either automatically or via any dialog.

Comment: _“(see field third_party_id)”_ - that never had anything to do with visiting a user profile in the first place. You could try the `link` field, that gives you a tokenized URL that can be called inside a user’s browser, and will redirect them to the real profile address. But that needs `user_link` permission from the user whose profile you want to visit first of all, and secondly the documentation suggests it should only work if the users are friends already. From my experience it seemed to work in other scenarios as well, but there’s no guarantee for that.

Comment: Do you know how to implement `link` field by react-native-firebase. As in the official document of firebase it is only provided by Javascript sdk https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/link